# Event Handler/Listener Unresponsive with Javascript/Html

Tags: javascript, html

Having issues with interactions of code. Trying to split presentation from logic with no success.

Tried splitting the functions called into separate listeners and also altered element ids just in case there was an incidental misidentification by either language, but no dice.

```
document.getElementById("clockInBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
clockIn('clockin');
resetBtnTxt('clockin', clock.inText);
});
```

Completely unresponsive.

EDIT:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Time Clock</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="timeclock2.css">
        <script src="timeclock2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="main">

            <h3 id="time">Current time is: </h3>

            <div class="btns-cont">
                <div class="btnstxt">
                    <p id="clockin">Clock-in time: </p>
                    <p id="clockout">Clock-out time: </p>
                </div>

                <div class="btns">       
                    <button type="button" id="clockInBtn">Clock In</button>
                    <button type="button" id="clockOutBtn">Clock Out</button>
                </div>

                <div  class="btnstxt">
                    <p id="breakout">Break-out time: </p>
                    <p id="breakin">Break-in time: </p>
                </div>

                <div class="btns">
                    <button type="button" onclick="breakOut('breakout'); resetBtnTxt('breakout', rest.outText)">Break Out</button>
                    <button type="button" onclick="breakIn('breakin'); resetBtnTxt('breakin', rest.inText2)">Break In</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>

var clock = {
    bool: false,
    in: 0,
    inText: "Clock-in time: ",
    inText2: "Already clocked in: ",
    out: 0,
    outText: "Not clocked in.",
    outText2: "Clock-out time is: "
};

var rest = {
    bool: false,
    out: 0,
    outText: "Break-out time is: ",
    outText2: "Already on break: ",
    in: 0,
    inText: "Not on break.",
    inText2: "Break-in time is: "
};

function clockIn(id) {
    switch (clock.bool) {
        case false:
            var d = new Date();
            var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
            clock.bool = true;
            clock.in = t;
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = clock.inText + clock.in;
            onClockIn();
            break;
        case true:
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = clock.inText2 + clock.in;
            break;
    }
};

function clockOut(id) {
    switch (clock.bool) {
        case false:
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = clock.outText;
            break;
        case true:
            var d = new Date();
            var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
            clock.bool = false;
            clock.out = t;
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = clock.outText2 + clock.out;
            onClockOut();
            break;
    }
};


function breakOut(id) {
    switch (rest.bool) {
        case false:
            var d = new Date();
            var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
            rest.bool = true;
            rest.out = t;
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = rest.outText + rest.out;
            break;
        case true:
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = rest.outText2 + rest.out;
            break;
    }
};

function breakIn(id) {
    switch (rest.bool) {
        case false:
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = rest.inText;
            break;
        case true:
            var d = new Date();
            var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
            rest.bool = false;
            rest.in = t;
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = rest.inText2 + rest.in;
            break;
    }
};

var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);
function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    var t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Current time is: " + t;
};

function resetBtnTxt(id, text) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = text;
    }, 3000);
};

function onClockIn() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
//    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
//        if (this.readyState != 4 && this.status != 200) {
//            alert("Connection error");
//        }
//    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "php-onclockin.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
};


function onClockOut() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
//    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
//        if (this.readyState != 4 && this.status != 200) {
//            alert("Connection error");
//        }
//    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "php-onclockout.php", true);
    xhttp.send();
};

function login() {
    $(function () {
        var text = $("#login").val();
        $("#btn0").click(function () {
            text += "0";
            $("#login").val(text);
        });
        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            text += "1";
            $("#login").val(text);
        });
        $("#btn2").click(function () {
            text += "2";
            $("#login").val(text);
        });
        $("#btn3").click(function () {
            text += "3";
            $("#login").val(text);
        });
        $("#btn4").click(function () {
            text += "4";
            $("#login").val(text);
        });
        $("#btn5").click(function () {
            text += "5";
            $("#login").val(text);
        });
        $("#btn6").click(function () {
            text += "6";
            $("#login").val(text);
        });
        $("#btn7").click(function () {
            text += "7";
            $("#login").val(text);
        });
        $("#btn8").click(function () {
            text += "8";
            $("#login").val(text);
        });
        $("#btn9").click(function () {
            text += "9";
            $("#login").val(text);
        });
        $("#btnReset").click(function () {
            text = "";
            $("#login").val(text);
        });
    });
}

document.getElementById("clockInBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    clockIn('clockin');
    resetBtnTxt('clockin', clock.inText);
});
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: can you include HTML and the rest of the javascript?

Comment: Added requested info.

Comment: Clock in listener works for me. https://jsfiddle.net/om4x5nhe/ (though, best to always attach handlers with `addEventListener` rather than inline attributes, which are as bad as `eval`)

Comment: Must be my IDE (using NetBeans) or some other glitch. I have serious issues with glitching when it comes to MANY things, and what sucks is that there is the practical problem of self-doubt and assuming you're wrong because the computer "can't be". May need a different IDE or something.